# Which type of transactions does waves platform have for smart accounts and smart assets?

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, wavesplatform, ride

How many transactions does waves have? will Waves Smart contracts add another transaction type to the waves platform? And where to find examples of those transactions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are currently 15 different types of transactions in the Waves Blockchain. Yes, Waves platform added a new transaction for setting a script which called [SetScript transaction](https://wavesplatform.github.io/waves-transactions/globals.html#setscript) and a new transaction for smart assets called [SetAssetScript transaction](https://wavesplatform.github.io/waves-transactions/globals.html#setassetscript).
You can check all [transactions examples here](https://docs.wavesplatform.com/en/waves-api-and-sdk/waves-node-rest-api/example-transactions.html).

Comment: Does gowaves (https://github.com/wavesplatform/gowaves) support all types (15) of transactions?